# How to disable swipe up and swipe down

Tags: swift, xcode, xlpagertabstrip

I am using XLPagerTabStrip and have a tab bar across the top of the screen. It scrolls fine left and right and works great, but for some reason it also scrolls up and down and I cannot figure out a way to top the behavior. I have read through the docs but cannot find a solution. Seems like a basic feature so I must have missed something.

Can someone help to direct me where I make a change so the the up and down scrolling is disabled, I just want left and right.

Thanks for the help.

Here is an image when app first launched: 
[image]

Here is what happens when I swipe up.
[image]
You will notice that the text is scrolling up, if I continue to swipe in that direction the text will disappear and scroll off the screen. Also, if I swipe down the text bounces much like when you pull a UITableViewDown... I do have Bounce Horizontally and Vertically un-checked as shown in the screen shot below:

[image]

It may be important to take note tat it also does not scroll left and right.  It is almost like it is only using the view width and wrapping the items.

Comment: disable vertical bouncing ;)

Comment: So I do have both Bounce Horizontally and Vertically off... unchecked for the view in interface builder.  I do no think that has anything to do with it.  I maybe should have mentioned that it does not scroll left and right either.

Answer (score 0):

In **PagerTabStripViewController** class viewDidLoad() method, make suer you have used the following code.

```
containerView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
containerView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
containerView.scrollsToTop = false
```